# How to get RoleAssignment programmatically from a SPFolder without .Item

Tags: folder, roles

I need to get the permissions associated to a Folder.
I can get the folder by the getfolder method but the item has the .Item property null.
When i Access to the .DocumentLibrary i get the RoleAssignments, but if I had a subfolder with his own RoleAssignments, the solution i'm using always returns me the parents' privileges..

here's some simplified code

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(singleSiteBinding.Url))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb()) 
                            {
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                siteCollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(singleSiteBinding.Url);
                                //  folder.Item == null!!

                                foreach (SPRoleAssignment ruolo in folder.DocumentLibrary.RoleAssignments)
                                {
                                    //DO SOMETHING!
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you sure you get the right folder? Is folder.Exists true? If this is a real folder then you should have an Item which has the RoleAssignments Property. The folder.DocumentLibrary is the doc lib which holds (or would hold) the folder and RoleAssignments of that is the doclibs roleassignments

Comment: Exactly.. I'm using wrong Path.. With the right one it works.. But not every time! There is a case in which i pass the right address, it gets the folder, the folder exists but the Item associated is null... This happens (in my case) for an URL who is a rootfolder URL... It's a normal behavior? I'm using the .DocumentLibrary to solve the problem!